# Finding the limit of trigonometric function

Tags: trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\to\frac{\pi}{4}}\tan(2x)\cdot\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-x\right)$$
How do I find the limit of this function without L'hospital rule.

Comment: Write $x = \frac{\pi}{4} - h$. Use $\tan \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - y\right) = \,?$

Answer (score 1):

Let $t=x-\frac\pi4$ then we write the given limit on this form ($\tan(2t+\pi/2)=-\cot(2t)$):

$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\tan t}{\tan 2t}$$
Now the result is clearly $\frac12$ using that

$$\lim_{t\to0}\frac{\sin t}{t}=1$$

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

$$\tan2x\;\tan\left(\frac\pi4-x\right)=\frac{\sin2x}{\cos2x}\frac{\sin\left(\frac\pi4-x\right)}{\cos\left(\frac\pi4-x\right)}=\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{\cos^2x-\sin^2x}\frac{\frac1{\sqrt2}\left(\cos x-\sin x\right)}{\frac1{\sqrt2}\left(\cos x+\sin x\right)}=$$

$$=\frac{2\sin x\cos x}{(\cos x+\sin x)^2}\xrightarrow[x\to\frac\pi4]{}0\frac{2\frac1{\sqrt2}\frac1{\sqrt2}}{\left(\frac2{\sqrt2}\right)^2}=\frac12$$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:*

Using the formula $\displaystyle \tan(a + b) = \frac{ \tan a + \tan b}{1 - \tan a . \tan b}$,

$$\tan 2x . \tan (\pi/4 - x) = \frac{2\tan x}{1 - \tan^2 x}.\frac{\tan\pi/4 + \tan(-x)}{1 - \tan\pi/4.\tan(-x)}$$

Simplify that expression and then try and take the limit

Answer (score 0):

simplifying your given term into
$2\,{\frac {\sin \left( x \right) \cos \left( x \right)  \left( \cos
 \left( x \right) -\sin \left( x \right)  \right) }{ \left( 2\,
 \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{2}-1 \right)  \left( \cos
 \left( x \right) +\sin \left( x \right)  \right) }}
$
and the searched limit is $\frac{1}{2}$